# RPC call to getLargestAccounts fails sometimes

Tags: web3.js

Why does a call to Connection.getLargestAccounts() sometimes just fail?
Currently I have a separate TypeScript file containing exported functions to handle caching:

```
const solConn: Connection = new Connection(SolanaApiURL.mainnet_beta, "confirmed");

export async function getLargestAccounts() {
    const cacheName = "getLargestAccounts";
    let result = await readFromCache(cacheName);

    if (result != null) {
        return result;
    }

    let largestAccounts = await solConn.getLargestAccounts();

    if (largestAccounts != null) {
        writeToCache(cacheName, largestAccounts, 20 * 1000);
    }

    return largestAccounts;
}
```

The problem lies with the line

```
let largestAccounts = await solConn.getLargestAccounts();
```

Sometimes it returns the actual 20 largest accounts of the current network, but sometimes it never finishes the async call and stops.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug with @solana/web3.js?

Comment: Ok, so the problem lies with the RPC call itself, I tried POSTing `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"getLargestAccounts"}` to https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com and it still only sporadically returns a response. So it's not a problem with @solana/web3.js but with the RPC call itself, which is weird imo.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you're getting rate limited.

https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints#rate-limits

Comment: I don't think I am, AFAIK @solana/web3.js notifies if the rate limit is exceeded. It also happens on the first request I send, so it's very likely just the "processing time" of the RPC call on the handling RPC node. Obviously going through the transaction history to find the 20 largest accounts is a work intensive task.